# Need to replace part of a string with another string

Tags: regex, perl

I'm still pretty new to perl and regex and need some help getting started.  I would love to provide some code, but that's kinda where I'm stuck.

What I'm trying to do is that I have this string in a file like this:

```
dn: CN=doe\, john,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com
```

and a string like this:

```
uid: d12345
```

I need to do a search and replace to get the following result.

```
dn: uid= d12345,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com
```

Can anyone help me get started with this one?  Much thanks!

Comment: You both answered my question, but I wasn't sure which answer to accept so I just took the first one.  Not sure the protocol on that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to replace `CN=doe\, john` with `uid= d12345`? Try this:

```
$uidString = "uid: d12345";
$dnString = "dn: uid= d12345,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com";

if( $uidString =~ /uid: (\w+)/ ) {
  $uid = $1;
  $dnString =~ s/CN=.+?[^\\],/uid= $uid,/;
}
```

That will replace everything from `CN=` to the first unescaped comma with the uid.

Comment: The uid value will be dynamic, so not necessarily d+5 digits so can't do a match for 5 digits.  It could be b123xyz, pin789abc, etc.  Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Okay, I changed it to `\w+`, which will match as many alphanumeric characters as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your DNs and uids will be dynamic. Here is something that will help. The regex will substitute `CN=` all the way until the comma with whatever string you put in `$uid`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'dn: CN=doe\, john,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com';
my $uid_str  = 'uid: d12345';
my ($uid) = $uid_str =~ m/^uid:(.+)$/;
$string =~ s/CN=.+(,OU=.+$)/uid=$uid$1/;

print "String is: $string\n";
```

Output: `String is: dn: uid= d12345,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com`

Comment: Output should look like this:  dn: uid= d12345,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com
Could you also help explain the regex to help me gain a better understanding?  Much thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning how to properly edit my posts too.  :(

Comment: Updated with a more correct output. This regex will Look for the literal string CN= and any characters after it until it finds a comma and the string OU=. It will replace everything from CN= up to the ,OU with the uid provided.

Answer (score 0):

Won't a one line regex do the trick?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = "dn: CN=doe\, john,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com";
my $b= "uid: d12345";
#the regex
$a =~ s/CN(.*?), .*?,/$b,/;

print "$a";
```